# Saving Session Variable with comma Seperated Values

Tags: c#

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static void GetDahboardWidgetRefresh(int Widget)
        {
 
            HttpContext.Current.Session["WidgetRefId"] = Widget+',';
            string myValues = HttpContext.Current.Session["WidgetRefId"] as string;
            
        }
```

I am calling this WebMethod on button_Click via Ajax call. There are several buttons which call this function with their respective widget. So if five buttons (btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5) are called with widget values 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 on distinct calls, I want to save it with comma separated values in the session variable. But the value for `myValues` is coming in as NULL. I am expecting it to be 1,2,3,4,5,. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static void GetDahboardWidgetRefresh(int Widget)
{
if(HttpContext.Current.Session["WidgetRefId"]==null)
HttpContext.Current.Session["WidgetRefId"] = "";
HttpContext.Current.Session["WidgetRefId"]= HttpContext.Current.Session["WidgetRefId"].ToString()+Widget +',';
string myValues = "";
myValues = HttpContext.Current.Session["WidgetRefId"] as string;
}
```

I made some changes and now its working fine.Thank You.